# how to calculate the difference between 2 rows using mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table MeterReading in mysql and it has the following columns

```
meterid bigint(4),
reading bigint(4),
date date,
time time,
consumption,
primary key(meterid,reading)
```

i am inserting the vlues to this table except consumption and my problem is how to update the table based on these values.

i tried the following query

```
update MeterReading a 
set consumption=(select reading-IFNULL((select MAX(reading) from MeterReading  where meterid=a.meterid AND (date < a.date OR date = a.date AND time < a.time )),0));
```

i want the result like:

```
  meterid | reading | date       | time     | consumption |
+---------+---------+------------+----------+-------------+
|       1 |     450 | 2012-10-05 | 06:05:05 |        450  |
|       1 |     550 | 2012-10-06 | 08:05:05 |        100  |
|       1 |     600 | 2012-10-07 | 09:05:05 |        50   |
|       1 |     700 | 2012-10-08 | 10:05:05 |        100  |
```

please help me

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Try this instead:</strike>

```
UPDATE MeterReading a 
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT meterid, MAX(reading) MaxReading
  FROM MeterReading
  GROUP BY meterid
) g ON g.meterid = a.meterid
SET a.consumption = IFNULL(g.MaxReading, 0) - a.reading ;
```

**Update:** Use `IFNULL(g.MaxReading, 0) - a.reading` or you can use the `ABS(IFNULL(g.MaxReading, 0) - a.reading)`.

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2664/1)

---

**Edit:** So, you need to update each composite key (`meterid`, `reading`)'s `consumption` value with the difference between the current reading value and the next row's reading value. If so you can do this:

```
UPDATE MeterReading m
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    m.*,
    @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
  FROM meterreading m, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
  ORDER BY m.date 
) t1  ON m.meterid = t1.meterid 
     AND m.reading = t1.reading
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT 
    m.*,
    @rownum2 := @rownum2 + 1 AS rank
  FROM meterreading m, (SELECT @rownum2 := 0) r
  ORDER BY m.date 
) t2  ON  t1.rank - t2.rank = 1
SET m.consumption = (t1.reading - IFNULL(t2.reading, 0));
```

### [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39bd8/2)

This will make your table `meterreading`, after update, looks like:

```
| METERID | READING |                           DATE |                           TIME | CONSUMPTION |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|       1 |     450 | October, 05 2012 02:00:00+0000 | January, 01 1970 06:05:05+0000 |         450 |
|       1 |     550 | October, 06 2012 02:00:00+0000 | January, 01 1970 08:05:05+0000 |         100 |
|       1 |     600 | October, 07 2012 02:00:00+0000 | January, 01 1970 09:05:05+0000 |          50 |
|       1 |     700 | October, 08 2012 02:00:00+0000 | January, 01 1970 10:05:05+0000 |         100 |
```

**Note that:** I used the `@rownum` variable to get each row's rank, and the thing is, this rank is based on the order of the `Date` column, so it will get the next date's reading value.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply but i am getting consumption values as negative i have edited my post please help me

Comment: @ArunKillu the `IFNULL` needs to be on the the `SET` clause not in the subauery, because of the `LEFT JOIN` so that you will expect `NULL` values for the `g.MaxReading`, then you can use the `CASE WHEN g.MaxReading IS NULL THEN ... ELSE something else END`. Another reason is that, inside the subquery you are grouping with the `meterid` and calculating the max of reading where these couples are comosite key so you didn't expect `NULL` values between them so there is no need to do so inside the subquery. It is legal to do so for any reason else.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply mahmoud gamal  but i am getting consumption values as negative i have edited my post please help me

Comment: @SaiSai that is because sum of n numbers is always greater than any of the numbers in {1....n}

Comment: @@MahmoudGamal thanks again but i need consumption values as i shown in mypost please help me to solve this

Comment: @SaiSai Sorry again for my late responses, but I was out of here. Can you please post the actual data in the table that you need to update them to become like what you post in your question? and please explain how the consumption value is calculated for each meterid. Of course, I will try to do my best to help you, but please I really need to understand what you really try to do. Thanks.

Comment: thanks again.i tried the query like update MeterReading a 
set consumption=(select reading-IFNULL((select MAX(reading) from MeterReading  where meterid=a.meterid AND (date < a.date OR date = a.date AND time < a.time )),0));

Comment: i have posted my table also